# How i can detect if 2d map field is "trapped" around collisions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, 2d

As in title, can i somehow detect if map field is trapped around collisions? So my idea is to make a function, where as parameters I put x, y of a field I want to check. If map field (one we can walk on) is trapped around collisions it returns true, if not false. I've thought about getting coordinates around specific x, y first, detect if it's a collision, if not, add another layer of coordinates on top of the one I generated, and so on. But I don't really know how to make it properly so it won't get huge if there are no collisions around.

I have some image here:

[image: EXAMPLE]

As you can see here I have 6 fields "trapped" around collisions, and I want to check random one, in this example, I'll choose the one with the yellow circle on it. Let's say it's on coordinates x: 10, y: 10.

As I mentioned before I was thinking about these layers of coordinates around specific x,y. And I made a function like this:

```js
function getNeighbors(x, y, layer) {
 let coordinates = [];
 let a = {x: x, y: y - layer},
  b = {x: x - layer, y: y - layer},
  c = {x: x + layer, y: y - layer},
  d = {x: x - layer, y: y},
  e = {x: x + layer, y: y},
  f = {x: x, y: y + layer},
  g = {x: x - layer, y: y + layer},
  h = {x: x + layer, y: y + layer}
 coordinates.push(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h);
 console.log(coordinates);
}

getNeighbors(10, 10, 1);
```

But maybe there is a better way of doing it...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're exactly looking for. Can you please expand on what you need? What is this "collisions" thingy you're talking about. Are you talking about the brown squares? Or is the collision the borders of each box and you're trynna detect if the yellow circle is inside the borders? Or are you trying to check if a green square is surrounded by brown squares.

Comment: @AbanaClara
Brown = Collision
Green = Field you (as a player) can walk on.
And i want to make a function named let's say FieldTrapped(x, y) {...} and it should detect if Field is surrounded by collisions if yes, it retuns true, if not false. Something like that

Comment: Okay but what is considered surrounded by collisions? If one field is trapped by four brown boxes or if any subsequent green box is eventually trapped by brown squares like in the pic? Sounds like it's the latter. So you said you want to *check random one* in the post. Check what? Check if any nearby field leads to being trapped?

Comment: @AbanaClara
Maybe i wrote some bs tho sorry. Lets say i know where the green field is located (x, y) i put it as a params to the function, and it's check if the field is surrounded by collision. If i check each field iside this "trap" it should output true for evey of them. Do you understand it better right now? Sorry, english is not my first language. >_<

Comment: Sounds very difficult to do by hacking through the coordinates. You should probably look at it on another angle. How about checking collisions by counting and calculating the grid position? Only viable if your 2d map is a quadrilateral tho i think

Comment: The map is 128x128 so it shoud work i guess?